# laravel searching belongsToMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables

- items ( id, item-name, catalog-name)
- categories (id, category-name)
- item_categories ( pivot table )

on Items model I made this relation

```
public function itemCategories() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categories');
}
```

In my controller I want to search all items from a catalog that belong to categories so i am trying this

```
$items = Items::where('catalog-name', 'somename')->whereHas('itemCategories', function ($query) {
    $query->where('category', 'something');
});
```

But I keep getting the error

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Items::itemCategories()

Any ideas what I am doing here ?

Comment: Sounds like that code is referenced elsewhere. If you're using linux or Mac, on the command line in your project directory try `grep -R itemWithCategories *`, to see where that's being referenced.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some extra information about where 'itemWithCategories' is used?

Comment: Sorry It was a typo .. I pasted something else.  Error updated.

Comment: I think the naming for model should be `Item` and `Category` first? Can you post whole models code pls? And you should make your belongsToMany clear by adding more parameters to it.